# Actionscript3 - Port forwarding and Sockets

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, port

I wrote an AIR app that uses socket to connect to another computer which is running another AIR application that uses ServerSocket to listen for incoming connections from the first app. Becuase my computer is behind a router, I have opened a port and forward it to the computer listening for connections. I checked in canyouseeme.org to see whether the port is opened or not and it said that this port is opened. When I tried to connect the first application to the second one it didn't connect. When started the second application and made it listen for incoming connections and check in canyouseeme.org, the app told me that the site did connect to it. So why the first AIR application couldn't connect??

Here is the code:

```
import flash.events.ServerSocketConnectEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;

var server:ServerSocket = new ServerSocket();
server.bind(55551, "192.168.1.4");
server.addEventListener(ServerSocketConnectEvent.CONNECT, handleConnection);
server.listen();

var socket:Socket = new Socket();
socket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, error)
socket.connect("94.59.206.37", 55551);

function error(event:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace("port 55551 is not openned");
}

function handleConnection(event:ServerSocketConnectEvent):void
{
    trace("connected!!");
}
```

Comment: Try removing the second part of the `bind` statement - it's not needed (it defaults to listening to all IP's)

Comment: I removed the ip from the bind function but it didn't solve the problem